# Need more information about exim4 log

Tags: linux, email, smtp, exim

Sometimes when I try to send a mail, I can see in exim4 mainlog,a line like this :
`address_mail R=dnslookup_users T=remote_smtp defer (98): Address already`
and the mail is put in exim queue, why ? I searched on web but I didn't find any good informations about this `remote_smtp defer (98)` what is it ? Why it's happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(It would have helped tremendously if you would not have left out half of the error message.)

So my **guess** is that it's been originally

> remote_smtp defer (98): Address already in use

in which case it would mean that when exim wanted to make the connection (*remote_smtp*) it was unable to bind to the IP address/port it wanted to use.
This could be caused by several things:

- it may be that you force exim to bind to an address which doesn't exist on the server;
- it could be that the address is already used by a different program; or
- it is possible that the address+port is already allocated, or all ports are in use.

Generally it is advised to run a standalone exim in debug mode to see exactly what's happening. You can try to deliver a message in the queue by issuing

> exim -d -M *msgid* | tee /tmp/exim_delivery_debug.log

and look for the specific message, and you should see exactly what address exim tries to bind to and what may cause the message. (If you specify **interface** in the *smtp driver* (*remote_smtp*) then try not to and see what's happening.)